# Cannot access to web-interface of DLink DAP-1360

Tags: router, wireless-router, wireless-access-point

I've just switched my DLink DAP-1360 to router mode from access point mode. Now I cannot access it by web. I've tried to open in browser my default gateway IP and got just ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED error. I've also tried to open every IP in local network with the same result. Then I resetted my DAP-1360 with hardware reset button, so I still have internet wifi sharing but cannot get to web interface also. How can I fix it?

Comment: I assume your using windows, correct me if I'm wrong. could you open up command prompt (press win+r key to open run, then type cmd) and type ipconfig. Let us know what your assigned ip is, and what your default gateway is set to. Also, try connecting to http://dlinkap that is the local address for your model, the ip is apparently 192.168.0.50

Comment: @Lister 192.168.0.50 worked fine for me, until DAP-1360 was in access point mode. But when I've switched it to router mode with reboot, I've never accessed it further. My IP: 10.23.42.55. Default gateway: 10.23.40.1.

Answer (score 0):

The repeater in general takes the IP address in the same range as the main router. So as soon as the repeater is connected to the main routers network, it gets rid of its current IP and takes the IP of the range and to access the repeater you must know what IP address the DHCP, which comes with the main router, has given to it.

To know what IP has been taken just scan all the devices connected to your main router and start to put every IP into your browser until you've found the IP of the repeater. I found out this solution myself, there are a lot of apps to do so just type in search ("wifi connected devices")!

Comment: While this might be true for a lot of cases it seems like this user changed the mode on his one router to be an AP instead of a router. Consider writing shorter sentences if your English isn't the best, it helps greatly to make it easier to understand.

Comment: "just" scan all the ip addresses lol